# Stretchable DIV issue

Tags: css, css-float

I'm currently working on this [page](http://newbarter.siteprogression.com/benefits-of-barter/) but the DIV containing  the overflowing text as seen on the given page  doesn't stretch to contain the text except when the height is changed from "auto" to a fixed "height" The CSS is as shown below:

```
.single #intro {
    width: 100%;
    height: auto;
    position:relative;
    float: left;
}
```

Comment: `height:auto;` works fine for me in IE9+, FF and chrome. What browser are you seeing issues in?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to make it stretch then you have multiple spots where height: needs to simply be deleted.

That is...

Here: (line 349)

```
#rack #main #intro #content-area {
    float: left;
    height: 370px;
    width: 750px;
    padding: 20px 30px 10px 30px;
}
```

And Here: (line 117)

```
#rack #main #intro {
    width: 100%;
    height: 400px;
}
```

Comment: That affects only the home page Michael. Note that the one that I'm referring to starts with ".single"

Comment: It should affect the entire site o.O  What other pages are there?  None of the other links work.  Irregardless, it's the multiple height's that are preventing your template from stretching.  If the above only hits the home page, then you have heights that are specific to other pages that you need to delete as well.

Comment: You're right Michael. I adjusted both and it now works fine. Thanks

Comment: You are quite welcome. =)  Feel free to message me if you have other problems.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `overflow` property to display a scrollbar, like this:

```
#rack #main #intro {
    width: 100%;
    height: 400px;
    overflow: auto;
}
```

That way you can mantain the height, but still show all content.

Answer (score 0):

your problem is with the footer div
once you use the float property, the next element just think that it should position it after the navigation bar
simply use

```
<div style="clear:both"></div>
```

or put the clear:both property to end of the content area div or the start of footer div

[you might need to float:right the content area to work this correctly]